# How can I replace a letter with two words within this array in Java

Tags: java

So, I already have a way to iterate through an array and have it so that every time the character "$" appears in a word, it will replace it with a word from an array sequentially.

Example:

Array= {"PUMPKIN", "BAT", "WITCH", "VAMPIRE"};

Word: C$$$$Y

Output: CPUMPKINBATWITCHVAMPIREY

But what I want to do is have it so that every $, two words will appear instead of one

Ex:
Word: C$$$$Y

Output: CPUMPKINBATWITCHVAMPIREPUMPKINBATY

As you can see, two words of the array come in for each $ and then it loops back around when the arrays finished. Is there a way to do this well? Ill leave the code I have below but it isnt working the way I want it to.

```
  public static String stickers(String data) {
        String strg = data;
        String search = "$";
        int numOfSigns = strg.replaceAll("[^" + search +"]", "").length();
        int ii = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSigns; i++) {
            if (ii > stickers.length -1) { 
                ii = 0; 
            }
            strg = strg.substring(0, strg.indexOf("$")) + stickers[ii]+stickers[ii+1] + strg.substring(strg.indexOf("$") + 1);
            ii++; 
        }
    
        return strg;
    }
```

Comment: what if ii == stickers.length -1 ?

Comment: also this is a good read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If you've already got a program that replaces `$` with one word, you could add a line to the beginning that replaces `$` with `$$`.

Comment: Im trying to implement that but nothing seems to work

Comment: "it isnt working the way I want it to." what's it doing?

Comment: Two things to think about: What number does `ii` need to increase by each time around the loop? What's a mathematical operator you can use to produce a number in a specified `0..n-1` range? (hint, read about the modulus operator, `%`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public class Main
{
    private static String[] array = {"PUMPKIN", "BAT", "WITCH", "VAMPIRE"};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "C$$$$Y";
        System.out.println(stickers(word));
    }
    
    public static String stickers(String data) {
        for(int i = 0; data.contains("$"); i += 2)
        {
            data = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("$")) + 
            array[i % array.length] + array[(i + 1) % array.length] + 
            data.substring((data.indexOf("$") + 1));
        }
        
        return data;
    }
}
```

This will produce output: **CPUMPKINBATWITCHVAMPIREPUMPKINBATWITCHVAMPIREY**